# Shorter syntax for Fold and FoldList?

Tags: functions, syntax, functional-style, core-language

I find it tedious to write out the following:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};

Fold[f, First @ a, Rest @ a]
```

> ```
> f[f[f[1, 2], 3], 4]
> ```

It becomes additionally cumbersome when working with held expressions, e.g.:

```
b = Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 3, 4 + 4];

SetAttributes[g, HoldAll];

b /. _[x_, __] :> Fold[g, Unevaluated[x], Rest@b]
```

> ```
> g[g[g[1 + 1, 2 + 2], 3 + 3], 4 + 4]
> ```

Likewise for `FoldList`.  Is there a shorter syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Good News Everyone!

#### Two-parameter syntax for `Fold` and `FoldList` has been (silently) implemented!

[Taliesin Beynon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7140/taliesin-beynon) informs me that this was implemented in 2011, so check your older versions as well.

*As [Naitree](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12863/naitree) notes this is now documented in 10.0.2:*

[image]
[image]

```
Fold[f, a]

FoldList[f, a]
```

> ```
> f[f[f[1, 2], 3], 4]
>
> {1, f[1, 2], f[f[1, 2], 3], f[f[f[1, 2], 3], 4]}
> ```

And the held expression example:

```
Fold[g, b]
```

> ```
> g[g[g[1 + 1, 2 + 2], 3 + 3], 4 + 4]
> ```

For full integration (versions 9.0 through 10.0.1) we merely need to update [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) to match the implementation:

```
Unprotect[Fold, FoldList]

SyntaxInformation[Fold]     = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _.}};
SyntaxInformation[FoldList] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _., {__}}};

Protect[Fold, FoldList]
```

(We could also update usage Messages if desired, but not doing so serves as a reminder that the function is undocumented in these versions.)

For older versions you may add the functionality itself with:

```
Unprotect[Fold, FoldList]

Fold[f_, h_[a_, b__]]     := Fold[f, Unevaluated @ a, h @ b]
FoldList[f_, h_[a_, b__]] := FoldList[f, Unevaluated @ a, h @ b]

Protect[Fold, FoldList]
```

**Special thanks to those who made this happen!**

Comment: Interesting! Thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I thought we had a discussion about it a while back - perhaps I forgot to mention that I could sneak it in;-) I am glad you like it.

Comment: It already works in M9 (Feb 7 2013 build).

Comment: @user21 I'm terribly sorry if I forgot or somehow confounded you with someone else.  (I have a very poor memory as I keep telling people.)  *Many thanks for getting this done!*

Comment: @YiWang, I think, IIRC, it works from V9 onward.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard How can I save the custom definitions for built-in symbols permanently? Is it `init.m` the correct choice? I searched the site but maybe I just couldn't pick a right keyword to the answer.

Comment: @Naitree I'll tell you what I do.  I use a single line in `init.m` to load a package which contains my own functions and customizations.  This makes it easy to "comment out" that line if needed.  I create, update, and manage the `.m` package file from a companion Notebook (`.nb`) with Initialization Cells; when you save such a Notebook for the first time it should ask you if you want to create a Package.  I save this Notebook/Package to the `Applications` directory under `$UserBaseDirectory`.  (continued)

Comment: For modifications to ``System` `` symbols you do not need to create a new Context but for your own functions I believe that you should.  However be aware that this can complicate access to your own functions from Cell contexts etc.; see: [(9571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9571/121) and 
[(13293)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13293/121).  Let me know if you run into any problems and I'll try to help, or just post a Question about it.

Comment: @Naitree By the way: be careful with modifying System functions.  There is a reasonable school of thought that says you should never do it.  There are usually alternatives, e.g. one could create a ``MyTools`Fold`` function and let this supersede the ``System`Fold`` function for interactive input.  Also be aware that in some cases your modifications may be undone by internal (re)loading; see: [(32531)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32531/121), [(63656)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63656/121).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Following your thorough instructions, I have successfully created a package file named `CustomDefinitions.m` under `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`, and put `<<CustomDefinitions/CustomDefinitions.m` in the `init.m` file which is under `$UserBaseDirectory/Kernel`. However, strangely I found out that the `init.m` file won't load automatically when I restarted Mma. I mean, the `init.m` takes effect only if I manually kick `<<init.m` after a fresh start of Mma. Also, I have checked that the default contexts of both `init.m` and `Untitled-1` are `Global`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Naitree Strange that your `Kernel/init.m` file isn't auto-loading.  It is possible to suppress loading with kernel launch flag `-noinit` as can be set from **Kernel Configuration Options...** but you would probably remember if you had set that.  If the problem persists I suggest you post a Question about it as other people may have more ideas.  (I cannot recall having that problem.)  Side note: it should be sufficient to use `<<CustomDefinitions.m` to load your package from that path as it should be in the `$Path` list.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I realized that `init.m` is evaluated automatically when the first input line of the session is being sent to the kernel. Not immediately after system start-up. So I think it actually works fine... :-)

Comment: @Naitree Ah, that's correct.  It is evaluated every time a kernel (without `-noinit`) is started, so if you terminate and restart a kernel or launch a new one your definitions should be loaded.

Comment: Hi again, @Mr.Wizard. I found out that two-argument form of `Fold` and `FoldList` has been offically documented in 10.0.2. See details section of their docs. :)

Comment: @Naitree Thanks for the note!

Comment: @user21 Is there now any reason not to implement an operator form for `Fold` such that `Fold[fn][list]` is equivalent to `Fold[fn, list]`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I was not involved in the operator form implementation, but I'll forward that as a suggestion.