# I'm trying to iterate a function with two variables

Tags: iterators

I have a function that calculates temperature that is dependent on both temperature and time. I want to be able to iterate the function to calculate a new temperature and then use that as the next temperature input of the function, and increase the time input by 1.

For example, if my function is `F[T,t]`, I want to be able to make it go through this sequence:

```
F[T0,t0]
F[F[T0,t0],t1]
F[F[F[T0,t0]],t2]
etc.
```

I think that I can do this with a combination of Fold and a For loop, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Comment: `Rest@FoldList[f, T0, {t0, t1, t2, t3}]`?

Comment: @kguler You can include `T0` in the list, FWIW.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thought that was a v10 feature; but it does work in v9 too.

Comment: Voting to close as this seems the very definition of `FoldList[]`

Comment: @kguler As noted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121) I was told that it was implemented in 2011.

Comment: @belisarius If Helen confirms my interpretation I shall join you.  If `F[F[F[T0,t0]],t2]` is *not* a mistake the question requires additional clarification.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After reading the OP's "spoken" description of the problem I got convinced that your interpretation is right and the posted sequence is wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard After reading somewhere from you the syntax shortcutting for `FoldList[]` it is so much lean now. Thanks again.

Comment: Helen, I am going to close this on the assumption that my interpretation, shared by belisarius, is correct.  If I am wrong please explain what you really need and I shall reopen.

Answer (score 3):

I think [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) alone will do what you want.  The output is slightly different from the sequence you show but I am assuming that is an error in the question.

```
FoldList[F, F[T0, t0], {t1, t2}]
```

> ```
> {F[T0, t0], F[F[T0, t0], t1], F[F[F[T0, t0], t1], t2]}
> ```

This could also be written:

```
FoldList[F, {T0, t0, t1, t2}] // Rest
```

> ```
> {F[T0, t0], F[F[T0, t0], t1], F[F[F[T0, t0], t1], t2]}
> ```

See: [Shorter syntax for Fold and FoldList?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)