# mixing color of individual parts of a function in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have a function which is a sum of three terms and I want to plot it in a DensityPlot. However, I would like that the ColorFunction would be the RGBColor resulting of the mixed R color corresponding to first term, G color of the second term and B color of the third term. I think that my problem is similar to that of combine RGB channels of a RGB image, but applied to an addition of three functions in a DensityPlot.

Any idea will be welcome. I have tried several things. However, as expected, I always could change only the color of the whole function as a function of z.

Thanks for your time.

Jose

Comment: Use `Blend` in your `ColorFunction`.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork mathematica does not inject the coordinates into the `ColorFunction`. Only the function value, and that is not enough for what the OP wants to achieve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
f[x_, y_] := {Sin[x], Cos[y], Sin[2 x + y]}

Block[{x, y, h, xMin = -1, xMax = 3, yMin = -3, yMax = 3}, 
 Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Show[ColorCombine[Table[Image[
        DensityPlot[f[x, y][[i]], {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}, 
         Frame -> None, ImageMargins -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
         ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ColorFunctionScaling -> None], 
        ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"], {i, 3}], "RGB"], 
     AspectRatio -> Full], {xMin, yMin}, {0, 0}, 
     {xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin}], Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> .08]]
```

[image: colors]

The main ingredient is to do the three function components as separate `DensityPlot`s, then apply `ColorCombine` to them, and insert the resulting `Image` into a `Graphics` frame with the same coordinate range as the original function.

For the last part, I use `Inset` with its three optional arguments to insure the correct positioning and stretching. The stretching to the correct aspect ratio only works if I first apply `Show` with the option `AspectRatio -> Full` to the image that is to be inserted.

I also added `ColorFunctionScaling->None` to `DensityPlot` so that you have control over the maximum and minimum ranges of your color channels. In the table of `DensityPlot`s, the color channel is first populated by `GrayScale` only. The colors are created by `ColorCombine`, but this only works for images with the colorspace specification `"Grayscale"`.

Comment: I expected a gray scale from black to white for `f[x_, y_] := {Sin[x], Sin@x, Sin@x}`. It seems I have scaling issues.

Comment: @belisarius Oh, yes - I messed up the use of `ColorCombine`. Let me fix it. Next time, I should look at the documentation before answering...

Comment: I just tried this code and got multiple errors of the type: `Image::imgcsmsw: The specified color space GrayLevel and the number of channels 3 are not compatible; using Automatic instead. >>`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it must be something in version 10 - I have version 8 right now and it works. I'll look at it when I can test in version 10... later today, I hope.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Does it work now? I changed `GrayLevel` to `Grayscale`.

Comment: Yes, it works now. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Seems like *Mathematica* is trying to remove gray areas from its syntax for grey areas.

Answer (score 4):

A possible alternative to [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) is to render an [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html):

```
(* kguler's example function *)
f[x_, y_] := {Sin[x] Sin[y], Sin[3 x] Cos[2 y], Cos[y/Pi] Sin[x + y]}


Array[f, {100, 100}, {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}}] // Transpose // Reverse //
 Rescale // Image // ImageResize[#, 300] &
```

[image]

---

Here is a self-contained function that evaluates a function and plots it as a [`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Raster.html), complete with axes:

```
plotAsRaster[
  fn_,
  points : {_, _} : {100, 100},
  ranges : {{_, _}, {_, _}},
  opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]
] :=
   Graphics[
     Raster[Rescale@Array[fn, points, ranges]\[Transpose], ranges\[Transpose]], 
     opts, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1
   ]
```

Test:

```
plotAsRaster[f, {{-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}}]
```

[image]

(This is not intended to be a well developed function but merely a proof of concept.)

A modification with interpolation:

```
plotAsRasterInterpolated[fn_, points : {_, _} : {100, 100}, ranges : {{_, _}, {_, _}}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[Graphics]] := 
 Graphics[Raster[
   ImageData@ImageResize[Image[Rescale@Array[fn, points, ranges]\[Transpose]], 3 points], 
   ranges\[Transpose]], opts, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 3 points]
```

Comment: Basically, that is what I did. However, I am also interested in showing the axes for more information about the plot content.

Comment: @José Please see my update.  I did not include interpolation in this example but if you find the idea otherwise pleasing I can include it.

Comment: Nice solution. However, why as "raster"? It looses resolution. The alternative as Inset in Graphics seems to be good.

Comment: @José It doesn't actually lose resolution, but it doesn't gain (apparent) resolution because I did not include interpolation.  If that is included it will look smoother.  I shall add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] := {Sin[x] Sin[y], Sin[3 x] Cos[2 y], Cos[y/Pi] Sin[ x + y]}

dp = DensityPlot[Plus @@ f[x, y], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

```
dps = DensityPlot[f[x, y][[#]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
     Frame -> False, ImageSize -> 300,
     ColorFunction -> (Function[{c}, RGBColor@RotateRight[{c, 0, 0}, # - 1]])] & /@ Range[3];
Row@dps
```

[image]

```
Fold[ImageAdd, dps]  (* thanks: Mr. Wizard *)
(* Fold[ImageAdd, First@dps, Rest@dps] in case the two-args version doesn't work *)
```

[image]

Comment: Your last line of code may be replaced with `Fold[ImageAdd, dps]` according to [(54784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121).

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard - how quickly i forget:)