# How do I achive the function of Continue using Catch and Throw?

Tags: procedural-programming

Procedural programming is considered a bad practice in writing Mathematica code. But for education's sake, is there any way I can do **Continue** using **Catch** and **Throw**?

According to WRI's documentation, the function of [Break](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Break.html) and [Continue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Continue.html) both can be achieved by using Catch and Throw. For the former one, an example is given: `Catch[For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, If[i > 2, Throw[Null]]]]; i` is equivalent to `For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, If[i > 2, Break[]]]; i`. For the latter, however, no example could be found. I googled for that, it seems no one asked the question. And I suspect that theoretically it can't even be done. Throw lets you quit a loop, how could it be used to jump to somewhere else in the loop as Continue does?

Answer (score 10):

If you wrap the body of the loop with `Catch`, then any `Throw` will act as `Continue`:

```
r = 0;
Do[Catch[
   If[EvenQ[i], Throw[Null]];
   r += i
   ], {i, 10}];
r
(* Out: 25 *)
```

(Example taken from the [documentation for `Continue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Continue.html).)

Comment: Using `Fold[]`: `Fold[Catch[If[EvenQ[#2], Throw[#], # + #2]] &, 0, Range[10]]`

Comment: @J.M. or `Fold[Catch[If[EvenQ[#2], Throw[#], # + #2]] &, Range[0, 10]]` via [(54784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54784/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I've been using version 10 for a while and I still haven't gotten the hang of two-argument `Fold[]`... :D

Comment: The question has the procedural programming tag, OP specifically mentioned procedural programming, OP's example is written in procedural style, `Break` and `Continue` are fundamentally procedural constructs... just a few of the reasons why I didn't use `Fold`.

Comment: I know; that's why I just left a comment. It was more to demonstrate how to emulate `Continue[]` in a functional version of the code. In any event, I'm not likely to trade `Continue[]` for `Catch[]`/`Throw[]` in most cases.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment.

I don't think procedural programming in Mathematica is always to be avoided. In particular, consider the following procedural code, a minor variation of the example given for the use of `Continue`.

```
r = 0;
Do[
  If[i > 8,
    Break[],
    If[EvenQ[i], Continue[], r += i]],
  {i, 10}];
r
```

> `16`

Now I write equivalent code with `Catch` and `Throw`

```
r = 0;
Catch[
  Do[
    Catch[
      If[i > 8,
        Throw[Null, 2],
        If[EvenQ[i], Throw[Null, 1]]; r += i],
      1],
    {i, 10}],
  2];
r
```

And here is the functional version based on the code proposed by J.M. and Mr.Wizard.

```
Catch[
  Fold[
    Catch[
      If[#2 > 8,
        Throw[#1, 2],
        If[EvenQ[#2], Throw[#1, 1], #1 + #2]], 1] &,
    Range[0, 10]],
  2]
```

I assert that the first example above has the great virtue of being both concise and clear, which means it is likely to be written without coding errors. Because of this and despite being tainted by procedualism, I think the first example has the best code of the three.

Comment: I agree that the first procedural snippet is the one with the clearest intent, but I don't like the word "tainted".

Comment: @J.M. That was meant to be irony. My motto is: proceduralism has its place.

Comment: Heads up: I just posted a rebuttal of this answer.  I await your counterargument. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I feel a bit uneasy about posting tangential commentary as answers but since this is too long for Comments here are my thoughts on m_goldberg's post.

I absolutely agree that procedural coding has its place in *Mathematica*.  Nevertheless I feel that the example given is misleading.  First a `Do` loop is already a level of abstraction above `For` and it is used quite often by experienced users.  (It is not representative of procedural code that people typically argue against.)   Second `Continue[]` is quite pointless in this example; one would instead just write:

```
r = 0;

Do[If[i > 8, Break[], If[OddQ[i], r += i]], {i, 10}]

r
```

The `Break` condition itself is also not really valid as it depends solely on the `Do` iterator which is never directly manipulated.  A more realistic example would be a condition on `r`, e.g.

```
r = 0;

Do[If[r > 5, Break[], If[OddQ[i], r += i]], {i, 10}]

r    (* 9 *)
```

This could be written with [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) in several ways:

```
NestWhile[If[OddQ[++i], # + i, #] &, i = 0, # <= 5 &]

NestWhile[# + i*Boole@OddQ[i++] &, i = 0, # <= 5 &]

NestWhile[# + i*Mod[i++, 2] &, i = 0, # <= 5 &]
```

I do not feel that the `Do`/`Break` code is objectively clearer here.

Of course this whole example is still contrived and I one could just write `Tr @ Range[1, 8, 2]` or `Sum[i, {i, 1, 8, 2}]` in actuality.

I know it is difficult to contrive an example that is simple enough without being too simple and I do not mean to attack a straw man, but examples should still actually exemplify what they purport to if at all possible, and I feel that this one does not.

Comment: I don't have a counterargument. I agree with what you say in this post. I just don't see it as a rebuttal of my post. My point was that using procedural forms supported by `Break` and `Continue` are not improved by ignoring existence those functions and substituting `Catch` and `Throw` on the basis that they are functional. That there are better functional approches that avoid the whole issue of using `Catch` and `Throw` seems undeniable, but criticizes the OP's question on a different level than the one I was focused on.

Comment: @m_goldberg I think I both (1) misinterpreted your answer, and then (2) misrepresented what I meant my post to be when I called it a "rebuttal."  I thought you were arguing that in this particular case `Do`/`Break`/`Continue` was cleaner than `Fold`, irrespective of the use of `Throw` and `Catch`.  I thought to make that case you needed a stronger example, which is why I set about poking holes in it.  But I actually think that there are times when procedural code really is "better," which again I thought you were arguing, and I was actually hoping to prod you into a better example. :^)

Comment: Sorry, some days I don't prod too good :-)

Comment: @m_goldberg LOL -- I hope you don't mind my laughing, because that was really funny.  Probably because I can strongly identify.

Comment: To be blunt, I felt that it was a really weak demo of `Continue[]`, but I might be biased because in all of the programming I've done, in this and other languages, I've almost always used `Break[]` (or its direct equivalent; sometimes all a language has is `goto` ;)), and I am having a hard time remembering an application where the use of `Continue[]` resulted in cleaner code than the `Break[]` equivalent.